# Expection Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError also with 1G

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I try to display a `CarouselView` with about 2-3 items I get the following exception:

> **Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError:** ''

Log:

> 03-24 16:00:33.505 E/Bitmap  ( 9249): OOM allocating Bitmap with
> dimensions 630 x 16777078

I increased the `Java` memory to 1G in the `AndroidManifest` but the problem remains

```
 <Frame x:Name="ViewMesi" IsVisible="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="40,30,40,0" HeightRequest="380" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="{x:DynamicResource BgColor}" CornerRadius="15">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="210"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="Seleziona mese"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="22"/>

                <controls:TintedImage x:Name="ArrowMesiIndietro" Grid.Row="1" Source="ArrowSmall" HorizontalOptions="Center" TintColor="Gray" Rotation="270"/>
                <Button x:Name="MesiIndietro" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="MeseIndietro_Clicked" IsVisible="false"/>
                
                <CarouselView
                    x:Name="CVMesi"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="15"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    PeekAreaInsets="110"
                    Loop="False">
                    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="6" SnapPointsAlignment="Center" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"/>
                    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="{x:DynamicResource TextColor}" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </CarouselView>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="200" Grid.Row="2" Margin="15,30,15,0" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Opacity="0.8" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="200" Grid.Row="2" Margin="15,0,15,51" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Opacity="0.8" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                <controls:TintedImage x:Name="ArrowMesiAvanti" Grid.Row="3" Source="ArrowSmall" HorizontalOptions="Center" TintColor="Black" Rotation="90"/>
                <Button x:Name="MesiAvanti" Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="MeseAvanti_Clicked"/>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <Button Text="Annulla" HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="{x:DynamicResource TextColor}" FontSize="14" Clicked="CancellaVistaMese_Clicked"/>
                    <Button Text="Ok" HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="{x:DynamicResource TextColor}" FontSize="14" Clicked="MeseSelezionato_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```

If I make the `Carouselview` visible inside, I get the exception, otherwise no

Comment: do you have a **630 x 16777078** bitmap in your app?

Comment: I have not. The exception comes only if I make the CarouselView visible. I have updated the code

Comment: @StefanoAPP Maybe you can delete TintedImage to try again, if it is the TintedImage's problem, you can try to use **FFImageLoading**.